# Ruby on Rails ambethia recaptcha without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use the ambethia recaptcha without a model object, with no luck. Can someone provide me with an example of using the ambethia recaptcha in a method without a model object?

For example, I am writing a method for forgotten password.

```
def forgotten_password
if (params[:email] =~ /\A[a-z]+[0-9]*(_|.|-){1}[a-z]*[0-9]*@{1}[a-z]{3,}.{1}(com|net|org|info|biz|me|edu|gov){1}\z/i).nil?
  flash[:warning] = "Invalid email!"
  redirect_to(forgotten_password_path)
else
  user = Profile.find_by_email(params[:email])
  unless verify_recaptcha
    flash[:warning] = "Email or captcha is incorrect!"
    redirect_to(forgotten_password_path)
  else

  end
end
```

end

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was that I was using a table inside the forgot email form. I'm not sure why that was causing the problems, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

May you try like this ?

```
def forgotten_password
if (params[:email] =~ /\A[a-z]+[0-9]*(_|.|-){1}[a-z]*[0-9]*@{1}[a-z]{3,}.{1}(com|net|org|info|biz|me|edu|gov){1}\z/i).nil?
  flash[:warning] = "Invalid email!"
  redirect_to(forgotten_password_path)
else
  user = Profile.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if !verify_recaptcha
    flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
    flash[:warning] = "Email or captcha is incorrect!"
    redirect_to(forgotten_password_path)
  else
    redirect_to success_path
  end
end
```